# How to I concatenate 2 columns into a unique text

Tags: concatenation

So I have the following

```
Product     Customer
1           ABC Ltd
2           EFG Ltd
3           XYZ Ltd
```

I want to create a list that has all combinations, meaning,

```
Product     Customer
1           ABC Ltd
1           EFG Ltd
1           XYZ Ltd
2           ABC Ltd
2           EFG Ltd
```

.... and so on.  I would be left with 9 entries in this eg.  and also to be dynamic so it updates if added or changed.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a database? A file? something different? What tools and/or programming languages are you using, or want to use?

Comment: Your question is too vague, please read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Any basic set of nested [for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop) loops in any programming/scripting language can likely produce the results you desire. For instance, in [Python](https://www.python.org/):

```
#!/path/to/Python3/python

# lists of strings to concatenate
products = ['1', '2', '3']
companies = ['ABC Ltd', 'EFG Ltd', 'XYZ Ltd']

# Nested 'for' loops
for product in products:
    for company in companies:
        print (product, '\t', company)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
1    ABC Ltd
1    EFG Ltd
1    XYZ Ltd
2    ABC Ltd
2    EFG Ltd
2    XYZ Ltd
3    ABC Ltd
3    EFG Ltd
3    XYZ Ltd
```

The values for *products* and *companies* could be read dynamically from e.g. updated text files using `for` loops as well. Again, in Python:

```
# Replaces e.g
# products = ['1', '2', '3']
# companies = ['ABC Ltd', 'EFG Ltd', 'XYZ Ltd']

products = []
companies = []

with open ('products.txt', 'r') as products_file:
    for line in products_file:
        products.append(line.strip())

with open ('companies.txt', 'r') as companies_file:
    for line in companies_file:
        companies.append(line.strip())
```

*ex. products.txt*:

```
1
2
3
```

*ex. companies.txt*:

```
ABC Ltd
EFG Ltd
XYZ Ltd
```